# Elasticsearch and MongoDB with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river, mongoosastic

While implementing elasticsearch with mongodb and nodejs, I am using  [mongoosastic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic) and [elmongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elmongo) module.
These are working very well. But I just want to find out what is the advantage of using [mongo-river plugin](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb) over node modules. And Is it necessary to use replica set when using river?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mongo-connector` instead.
you can learn more about `mongo-connector` in my blog. here is the [link](http://sujitshakya.com.np/?p=236)

Comment: link is broken. Also, try to summarize what is in that page , in case , the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

River doesn't update in realtime, it reads oplogs from mongodb, and this can delay updates.
The oplog has a finite capacity as a capped collection and when its full it works like a circular queue, replacing the oldest entries with new entries.

Comment: @ishakya I have one thing to share with you well could you lemme know how you did above one because i am unable to please update me regarding it 
Thanks With REgards